# Need to verify request response which will be fetch from csv file and validate

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

[image]Need to verify request-response which will be fetched from CSV file and validate

I have CSV file which has two column request and response, I want to write a script which will fetch the value from CSV file and validate whether the response matches with the server response

[image]

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: Dmitri T - Solved my issue but still there is "," comma in my response, after comma the responses is not getting in assertion, Can you please help to get the complete response even if the comma present

Comment: I have provided the answer, use quotes in your csv file to separate Request and Response

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming that you have `test.csv` file which looks like:

   ```
   some request 1, expected response 1
   some request 2, expected response 2
   some request 3, expected response 3
   ```
2. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to your Test Plan, most probably the correct location would be as a child of the HTTP Request sampler which response you want to validate and configure it like:

   [image]
3. Use `${request}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where you need to provide the request data from the CSV file
4. Add [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved/) as a child of the request which response you want to validate
5. Configure it as follows:

   [image]
6. That's it, each iteration of reach virtual user will read the next line of the CSV file and validate whether the response contains the expected data. 
   [image]

Comment: there is "," comma in my response, after comma the responses is not getting in assertion, Can you please help to get the complete response even if the comma present

Comment: Set `Allow quoted data` to `True`

Answer (score 0):

If your Response contains any value with delimiter. [More about CSV_Data_Set_Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

1. CSV will look like this

[image]

2. Test Plan will look like this

[image]

3. CSV Data Set Config : `Allow quoted data to TRUE`

[image]

4. Add Response Assertion as a child of your Sampler Request with following ${response} parameter

[image]

Comment: Error is showing as "java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 33: https://reqres.in/api/users?page=<EOF>/", I have mention http request as "reqres.in/api/users?page=${request}"

Comment: Check your CSV settings, keep the one I shown in image. Recycle on EOF as TRUE.

Comment: If you want to stop the test if your CSV lines are done, then use the setting as Recycle on EOF as FALSE and Stop Thread on EOF as TRUE. It all depends upon you, how you want to run the test.

Comment: I tried Recycle on EOF as TRUE and False but still getting the same error, my request is showing as https://reqres.in/api/users?page=<EOF>/

Comment: Can you show your CSV file and CSV Data Set Config settings?

Comment: please check I have added the screenshot

Comment: Please check I have added screenshot